# what is the best method to encrypt and decrypt a value using c#?

Tags: c#, encryption

Hai guys,
   I hve a web page that has to send an encrypted value to another page in my asp.net web application... I want to know

- what is the best method to encrypt and decrypt a value using c#?

Comment: efficient? As in fastest? probably rot 13. http://www.tech-faq.com/rot-13.shtml

Comment: What Matt suggests assumes an awfully liberal definition of 'encrypt'.  But it makes the point - you need to define what you mean by encryption.  Do you mean "so a casual observer can't read it" or do you mean "I don't want the NSA to know what's being passed"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by efficient you mean efficient development (not implementing your own solution), I would say using the algorithms in the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace.  If instead you mean least-CPU-intensive, then probably rot 13 as mentioned by Matt Ellen.  (Edit: As others have mentioned, rot 13 is not secure.  Please consider that carefully.)

Between DES, 3DES, RC2, and Rijndael, [this is what MS has to say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978415.aspx):

> With small data, we find that
>   Rijndael, an AES (Advanced Encryption
>   standard), is the fastest of all the
>   methods. It has a variable block
>   length and key length, which may be
>   chosen to be any of 128, 192, or 256
>   bits. It also has a variable number of
>   rounds to produce the cipher text,
>   which depends on the key length and
>   the block length.

Answer (score 2):

The method would depend on your use. I would not use rot 13 as it's nothing more than a basic letter replacement; not very secure.

I'd use 3DES or AES for any encryption.